# Why does Extracting JSON data giving an exception?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to extract json object values from a url which is giving a json array.i tried removing **Toast.maketext()** from the  doinginbackgound method. But its crashing.Please help. Code is as following:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static ArrayList<Bitmap>bitmap=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> json= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    private static String url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=7b414d5858e1af7c06a9fb87a11ea64b";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Background().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=7b414d5858e1af7c06a9fb87a11ea64b");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class Background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            JsonParser j=new JsonParser();
            JSONArray air=j.getJsonFrmUrl(url);

            for(int i=0;i<air.length();i++) {
                try{
                    JSONObject c=air.getJSONObject(i);
                    String image="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + c.getString("backdrop_path");
                    String id=c.getString("id");
                    String title=c.getString("original_title");
                    HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("backdrop_path", image);
                    map.put("id", id);
                    map.put("original_title", title);
                    json.add(map);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    bitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image).getContent()));

                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your error is... ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noted down from your code :-

1. One Typo in method name :-

   ```
    @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
     JsonParser j=new JsonParser();
     JSONArray air=j.getJsonFrmUrl(url); // it should be getJsonFromUrl()
     .....
   }
   ```
2. Your `JSON` from the given url looks like this, where `results` is an `JSONArray` :-

   ```
   {
   "page": 1,
   "results": [
       {
           "adult": false,
           "backdrop_path": "/dkMD5qlogeRMiEixC4YNPUvax2T.jpg",
            ....
       }
            ],
   "total_pages": 11759,
   "total_results": 235162
   }
   ```

And you are parsing it like :-

```
JSONArray air=j.getJsonFrmUrl(url);
```

You should do it instead like :-

```
JSONObject inputObj = j.getJsonFrmUrl(url);
 JSONArray air = inputObj.getJSONArray("results");
 for(int i=0;i<air.length();i++){ // your logic}
```